# How do I listen to global hardware keyboard events?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-plugin, nativescript-vue

I am attempting to listen for global events on the entire NativeScript application for single & combo key presses.

After doing some research, I have found some info on how to accomplish this in Objective-C

- UIKit's UIKeyCommand: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeycommand
- Objective-C Classes: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/types/ObjC-Classes
- React-Native implementation: https://github.com/envoy/react-native-key-commands

I am a JavaScript developer, with 0 experience in Objective-C. So I'm not able to wrap my head around how to interpret this inside NativeScript.

I've found that the iOS `UIKeyCommand` class is available globally, however, when I try to initialize it using `UIKeyCommand.init("X")` it throws an error, saying "expecting 0 arguments"

Could anyone here provide some insight on this?

Comment: You will have to use `UIKeyCommand.keyCommandWithInputModifierFlagsAction("KeyToListen", null, "selector")` then add the return value (`UIKeyCommand`) to your `UIViewController` implementation, using `addKeyCommand(command)` method.

Comment: What does "selector" mean in this context?

Comment: The call back function name in your UIViewController.